# Retrieving Facebook friends list

Tags: facebook

I am not able to get the Facebook friends list using the API. It was working fine earlier but not anymore. Here is the code I have used. Can someone help to validate the code. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('PHPMailerConfig.php');
require_once("facebook/facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '***************';
$config['secret'] = '*******************************';
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
if(!empty($_GET['error'])) {
echo "User cancelled the authentication with facebook";
echo "<script>
window.opener.location.href='merror.php';
window.close();
</script>";
exit;
}
if($uid) {
$url = $uid.'?fields=id,work,friends,email,picture.width(450).height(450)';
$user_profile = $facebook->api($url);
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); 
$d = ''; 
foreach($friends['data']as $val) {
$d .= $val['id'].',';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is not working? You know you will just get app friends and not all friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the docs before posting a question which has been answered here hundreds of times.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends#read

> - A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.